# Is it more efficient to maintain a temperature or heat a space from scratch

Tags: thermodynamics

Which is a more efficient way to heat a home, based on 2hrs to heat up / cool down 7C.

For this example we will presume the home is heated with water radiators powered by a gas combi (tank less) boiler.

**OPTION 1**

- 6am : 23C set point
- 10am : 16C set point
- 3pm : 23C set point
- 11pm : 16C set point

**OPTION 2**

- 6am : 23C set point (23C is reached in 2 hours then for the rest of the day the thermostat will achieved 23C, let the temperature drop to 22C, then top it up to 23C again)
- 11pm : 16C set point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of heat the heating system puts in the house over the course of a day is equal to the amount lost by the house to the environment.

The rate of heat loss increases with the temperature of the house. Since the average temperature of the house in the first scenario is lower than in the second scenario, the first scenario is more economical.